# Excel: How can I divide on column with year values into 2 columns with range?

Tags: excel

I'm relatively new to excel, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
     A
1  YEAR(S)
2  1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972
3  1967,1968,1969
4  1970,1971
5  1990
```

I would like to have column "B" to be YearFrom and column "C" to be YearTo, and look something like this:

```
     A                                   B            C
1  YEAR(S)                            YearFrom      YearTo
2  1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972       1967          1972
3  1967,1968,1969                      1967          1969
4  1970,1971                           1970          1971
5  1990                                1990          1990
```

On row 5, I can just copy and paste it, but how can I code a range out of years in column A? Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B2:

```
=--LEFT (A2,4)
```

C2:

```
=--RIGHT(A2,4)
```

and copy down.

Comment: I like the double unary approach.

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.